# Finding the amount of letters a word has but making sure the program doesnt count puctuation as a letter

Tags: python

```
file=open("apple.txt","r")
letters=0
for line in file:
 words=line.split()
 for character in words:
     character = int(character)
     if character<=90 and character>=65:            #ascii code for the uppercase letters
         letters+=1
     elif character<=122 and character>=97:         #ascii code for lowercase letters
         letters+=1
print(letters)
```

The error i get is if int(character)<=90 and int(character)>=65:ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'I' Im not too sure what. Also my txt file contains I ate apples. 123
I am trying to make it so it will only count the letters I ate apples so I should see only see 10 letters when the program goes through. If someone can help with this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: To convert a char (more exactly a string of length 1) to an integer you need `ord()`, not `int()`. But why convert at all? Just do `'A' <= character <= 'Z' or 'a' <= character <= 'z'`

Comment: `for character in words` should be `for word in words` ...no?

Answer (score 0):

The function you need is `ord` instead of `int`, because you want to get the ASCII value of a character.

For example, `ord("A")` will give 65.

```
file=open("apple.txt","r")
letters=0
for line in file:
 words=line.split()
 for character in words:
     character = ord(character) # Get ASCII value associated with this character
     if character<=90 and character>=65:            #ascii code for the uppercase letters
         letters+=1
     elif character<=122 and character>=97:         #ascii code for lowercase letters
         letters+=1
print(letters)
```

Comment: okay so i changed the int to ord but now im getting the error  ord() expected a character, but string of length 3 found.

Comment: @user20232221 that's because your code split the input into words, not characters as your variable naming implies.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a word, it's easy to remove punctuation and count characters:

```
from string import punctuation

letters += len(c for c in word if c not in punctuation)
```